# Get a single pixels transparency in a bufferedimage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I can't find a way to get the transparency from a single pixel in a buffered image. I can get the RGB but not the transparency please help!

Comment: `new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y), true).getAlpha()`?

Comment: Thanks don't know why I didn't think of that ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)